# find a value other than a root with fsolve in python's scipy

Tags: python, scipy, root, solver

I know how I can solve for a root in `python` using `scipy.optimize.fsolve`.

I have a function defined 
`f = lambda : -1*numpy.exp(-x**2)` and I want to solve for `x` setting the function to a certain nonzero. For instance, I want to solve for `x` using `f(x) = 5`.

Is there a way to do this with `fsolve` or would I need to use another tool in scipy? In other words, I'm looking for something analogous to Maple's `fsolve`.

Answer (score 4):

This is easy if you change your definition of `f(x)`.  e.g. if you want `f(x) = 5`, define your function: `g(x) = f(x) - 5 = 0`